# use default android calender in an app

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar

i am working in an app that requires a calender. The default android calender of android JB 4.2.2 is the perfect match for the requirements for the app.

Can we use the default android calender in our app and customize it? If yes, please share the resources you have on using the default android calender in an app and customize as per need.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you need the whole view or just the events from the calendar?

Comment: i need the whole view of the calender inside my app. adding custom functionality in the calender is the plan. is there any library provided by android to use the default calender inside an app??

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. You can only access the events from the calendar provider.